# Fill Down based on pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 4 columns - City, Locality.Name, Buy.Rates and Buy.Rates.1. If a value in these columns (Locality.Name, Buy.Rates and Buy.Rates.1) are same, take the value and populate it in a new column called  'Updated.City'. Use that value until a new value appears it

```
structure(list(City = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("delhi-ncr", "gurgaon", "noida", 
"greater-noida", "ghaziabad", "faridabad", "mumbai", "bangalore", 
"chennai", "hyderabad", "pune", "kolkata", "ahmedabad", "bhubaneswar", 
"coimbatore", "indore", "nagpur", "vadodara", "chandigarh", "jaipur", 
"lucknow", "surat"), class = "factor"), Locality.Name = c("Delhi East", 
"Akshardham", "Dilshad Colony", "Dilshad Garden", "I P Extension", 
"Delhi South", "Adhchini", "Alaknanda", "Ashram", "Aya Nagar", 
"Chattarpur"), Buy.Rates = c("Delhi East", "Rs. 16,150 - 18,190/sq. ft.", 
"Rs. 5,398 - 6,290/sq. ft.", "Rs. 6,290 - 8,372/sq. ft.", "Rs. 8,288 - 9,435/sq. ft.", 
"Delhi South", "-", "Rs. 10,710 - 12,070/sq. ft.", "Rs. 9,520 - 11,008/sq. ft.", 
"-", "Rs. 3,485 - 4,760/sq. ft."), Buy.Rates.1 = c("Delhi East", 
"-1.7%", "-10.19%", "7.01%", "0.96%", "Delhi South", "-", "-3.24%", 
"-", "-", "7.78%")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 73L, 74L, 75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired Output (Added column 'Updated.City')

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
|   City    | Updated.City | Locality.Name  |          Buy.Rates          | Buy.Rates.1 |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| delhi-ncr | Delhi East   | Delhi East     | Delhi East                  | Delhi East  |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi East   | Akshardham     | Rs. 16,150 - 18,190/sq. ft. | -1.70%      |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi East   | Dilshad Colony | Rs. 5,398 - 6,290/sq. ft.   | -10.19%     |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi East   | Dilshad Garden | Rs. 6,290 - 8,372/sq. ft.   | 7.01%       |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi East   | I P Extension  | Rs. 8,288 - 9,435/sq. ft.   | 0.96%       |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi South  | Delhi South    | Delhi South                 | Delhi South |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi South  | Adhchini       | -                           | -           |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi South  | Alaknanda      | Rs. 10,710 - 12,070/sq. ft. | -3.24%      |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi South  | Ashram         | Rs. 9,520 - 11,008/sq. ft.  | -           |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi South  | Aya Nagar      | -                           | -           |
| delhi-ncr | Delhi South  | Chattarpur     | Rs. 3,485 - 4,760/sq. ft.   | 7.78%       |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Updated.City = if_else(Locality.Name == Buy.Rates & Locality.Name == Buy.Rates.1,
                                Locality.Name, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(Updated.City, .direction = "down")
```

This first creates `Updated.City` with either the value of `Locality.Name` or `NA`, and then fills the column down, replacing `NA`s.

This gives

```
        City  Locality.Name                   Buy.Rates Buy.Rates.1 Updated.City
1  delhi-ncr     Delhi East                  Delhi East  Delhi East   Delhi East
2  delhi-ncr     Akshardham Rs. 16,150 - 18,190/sq. ft.       -1.7%   Delhi East
3  delhi-ncr Dilshad Colony   Rs. 5,398 - 6,290/sq. ft.     -10.19%   Delhi East
4  delhi-ncr Dilshad Garden   Rs. 6,290 - 8,372/sq. ft.       7.01%   Delhi East
5  delhi-ncr  I P Extension   Rs. 8,288 - 9,435/sq. ft.       0.96%   Delhi East
6  delhi-ncr    Delhi South                 Delhi South Delhi South  Delhi South
7  delhi-ncr       Adhchini                           -           -  Delhi South
8  delhi-ncr      Alaknanda Rs. 10,710 - 12,070/sq. ft.      -3.24%  Delhi South
9  delhi-ncr         Ashram  Rs. 9,520 - 11,008/sq. ft.           -  Delhi South
10 delhi-ncr      Aya Nagar                           -           -  Delhi South
11 delhi-ncr     Chattarpur   Rs. 3,485 - 4,760/sq. ft.       7.78%  Delhi South
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution. The main step is the creation of an logical index vector where `TRUE` means that the three values are equal. Then use that index to assign the values in the new column and fill down the `NA`'s.

```
i <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) all(x == x[1]))
df1$Updated.City <- NA_character_
df1$Updated.City[i] <- df1$Locality.Name[i]
df1$Updated.City <- zoo::na.locf(df1$Updated.City)
df1
#        City  Locality.Name                   Buy.Rates Buy.Rates.1 Updated.City
#1  delhi-ncr     Delhi East                  Delhi East  Delhi East   Delhi East
#2  delhi-ncr     Akshardham Rs. 16,150 - 18,190/sq. ft.       -1.7%   Delhi East
#3  delhi-ncr Dilshad Colony   Rs. 5,398 - 6,290/sq. ft.     -10.19%   Delhi East
#4  delhi-ncr Dilshad Garden   Rs. 6,290 - 8,372/sq. ft.       7.01%   Delhi East
#5  delhi-ncr  I P Extension   Rs. 8,288 - 9,435/sq. ft.       0.96%   Delhi East
#70 delhi-ncr    Delhi South                 Delhi South Delhi South  Delhi South
#71 delhi-ncr       Adhchini                           -           -  Delhi South
#72 delhi-ncr      Alaknanda Rs. 10,710 - 12,070/sq. ft.      -3.24%  Delhi South
#73 delhi-ncr         Ashram  Rs. 9,520 - 11,008/sq. ft.           -  Delhi South
#74 delhi-ncr      Aya Nagar                           -           -  Delhi South
#75 delhi-ncr     Chattarpur   Rs. 3,485 - 4,760/sq. ft.       7.78%  Delhi South
```